# Class diagram for online store

Tags: database, uml, class-diagram

I need help on designing database table for online store. Here is my class diagram :

[image]

So I wonder is there anything wrong with my tables? Because it all seems separated. For example, this is how my online store works. First, needy resident creates product which link the Store needy resident table to Product table. Then, when customer order product, the information of needy resident would be pass along from product table to ordered product table. After that, I check for payment. If the ordered product status is paid, the ordered product price would be pass to Payment table and from the Payment table, I can update my Store needy resident's sales amount. It's very complicated and I am quite blur of it also.

So my question is, can somebody please help me check if my class diagram got some error for linking?

Thanks in advance.